Are these mallards or some other kind of duck?
I stumbled across these ducks in a park in Western Germany. They did not look like mallards to me but this is what image searches and bird identification apps want me to believe. Can anybody confirm that or tell me what other species they are? 

Definitely not pure Mallard, as males stand out by their white collars and green heads, females by uniform brown with light flecks. I'm not seeing anything in Google that resembles what you have here - maybe a cross or mutation...? Perhaps a rare breed.

They are hybrid ducks for sure, maybe Brewer's (Mallard x Gadwal) Ducks, common in Europe. Brewer's have high variation in coloring.
